# Settings bundle, want to show dynamic data from web-service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, settings.bundle

Hi I am stuck please help me...

Is it possible to load dynamic data in the settings bundle, exactly what i need is when user sets a value for a preference, i need to display a list for the next preference, this list should be drawn from an online database. I have seen some thing similar in iPhone's default settings. Can anybody please give a solution for this as i am really screwed now. If it is not possible then i will include the settings in the app itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not all features available to the iOS operating system is available to third-party applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to have dynamic values in Apple's settings application; they need to be specified in `Settings.bundle` before compilation. I recommend you implement a custom settings screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added a settings tab inside the application