# Localized String Formatting in Settings.bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I'm rather new to iOS development, which I'm sure will come as a big shock if you continue reading..  lol...

I have a question on using a Settings.bundle in my application.  I've already got it setup, and I had great success thus far with it, but I came across something I'm not sure how to handle, and not sure if it can even **BE** done.

What I'm doing is adding Footer text to the end of my Groups in the Settings.  Now, since I'm writing a localized application, I'd like to be able to do string formatting, or string substitution in my footer text string.  For example say I have the following in Root.strings:

```
"DEFAULTS_FOOTER"="This allows %@ to operate without you having to switch the settings each time.";
"APP_NAME"="My iOS App";
```

Then, as you'd expect, in my Root.plist file, I have something like:

```
...    
    <key>FooterText</key>
    <string>DEFAULTS_FOOTER</string>
...
```

So, does anyone know if it is at all possible to DO string substuitions, or formatting in this case?  Now, to be honest, I have not tried anything simple like:

```
"DEFAULTS_FOOTER"="This allows " + APP_NAME + " to operate without you having to switch setting each time.";
```

I have a feeling that Xcode (or would it be IB?) does not quite allow this type of syntax...  I *AM* going to try this, however, while I await replies to this question.

If anyone knows of a way that this CAN be done, I'm all ears.  And if you are wondering *WHY* I'd want to do something like this, just keep in mind that the above is JUST an example.  I know that most apps will not just up and change names, even between versions, but I DO have a need for this, and since it's LOCALIZED, I can locate the substituted string wherever in the main string that the language requires it.

Thank you in advance, for any help...

Comment: What you did has worked for me perfectly, just don't forget that when you localize it, it will be a string to format, as in:

NSString *localized = ....;
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:localized, parameter];

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800542/settings-bundle-want-to-show-dynamic-data-from-web-service

Answer (score 0):

I believe the preferred string concatenation method is as follows:

```
NSString* default = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DEFAULTS_FOOTER",APP_NAME];
```

Obviously you will want to do you look ups for localization prior to this...

Comment: This obviously doesn't happen IN the settings.bundle, so if that was your question this won't work.